# Why dd does not overwrite existing data?

Tags: dd

When I write random data on the disk with the dd tool, I can access the old data again.
To test it, I first added a "text.txt" file to the disk and wrote "this is text" in it.
My disk is mounted to the /mnt/backup directory.

```
$ cat /mnt/backup/text.txt
this is text
$
```

The i used dd:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb1 #this is the disk mounted to the /mnt/backup directory
1025+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1,1 GB, 1,0 GiB) copied, 14,4948 s, 74,1 MB/s
$
```

If I try to list the contents of the disk, I get no results, but when I type the full filename, I can print the contents of the file.

```
$ ls -l /mnt/backup/
total 0
$ cat /mnt/backup/text.txt
this is text
```

Why is this happening ? What I expected was that the existing data would also be overwritten. If I know the full filename I can still access the data. What is the point I missed?

Comment: `dd` is widely believed to be an abbreviation of "disk destroyer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data probably is overwritten, but some of it is still cached in memory.

When you write directly to the device like this, it bypasses the linux filesystem caching mechanism and goes directly to the device.  What is in cache at the time is at least temporarily unaffected.  If the filesystem is still mounted, the operating system may even write some dirty pages back to the disk after you have wiped it with dd.

However, linux may eventually notice that the filesystem is corrupted, and this could cause a kernel panic.

For best results, filesystems should be unmounted before you start scribbling directly on the device.